# Monitoring a virtual memory area (Win32)

Tags: winapi, memory-management

Is there any Win32 API function for monitoring a particular area in a program's virtual memory. For example, a notification message's spawn if there's a read/write operation upon the area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [guard pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) along with [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (probably in a loop) for monitory memory regions, for code sections you'd need to use [HW](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/hardwarebreakpoint.aspx) or SW (`INT3`) breakpoints, this requires writing a small, mini-debugger, such as [this tutorial shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but I've got a trouble with the approach using guard pages. In the article named "Creating Guard Pages", MSDN states that:

Comment: @anhldbk: seems part of the comment got cut off, what are you having problems with?

Comment: @Necrolis: :( I didn't mention that. Sorry! Every comment has a limited size. Please follow this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windbg/thread/d8548676-d454-4958-98e2-1eafed10a3a5/

Comment: @anhldbk: you want a custom exception filter set with `SetExceptionHandler` that handles your guard pages and tells them to continue, you can also use HW and SW breakpoints to do the same thing as well

Comment: @Necorlis: I used __try{} __except instead. But it doesn't work as the way I want. See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windbg/thread/d8548676-d454-4958-98e2-1eafed10a3a5/

Comment: @anhldbk: you need to reset the guard page every time its triggered, thats why its called a one-shot exception

Comment: @Necrolis: I should call VirtualProtect() in  the exception handler to modify the protection on that area. I did follow what you advised but it resulted in an endless loop :(
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windbg/thread/d8548676-d454-4958-98e2-1eafed10a3a5/

Comment: @anhldbk: your exception handler should set a flag in the debugger loop to reset the region, but for the looped example you give, a breakpoint would work better(though software ones are really slow, hardware ones are really limited)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can do this is through the [debugger api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551059%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).